# Linking images to different views

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, view, sencha-touch-2

I would like to link images to different views. I have searched Sencha docs and videos but can't resolve this issue. MyApp application contains 3 views: main, home, setting, firstpage 1 controller: maincontroller i want to link first image from home(view) to firstpage(view)

**App.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'touch/src',
    'MyApp': 'app'
});
viewport: {
        layout: {
            type: 'card',
            animation: {
                type: 'fade',
                direction: 'left',
                duration: 300
            }
        }
    }
//</debug>
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    requires: [      'Ext.MessageBox'    ],
    views: [        'Main', 'home', 'setting','firstpage'  ],
    controllers: [ 'maincontroller' ],
    icon: {
        '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },
    isIconPrecomposed: true,
    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
    },
    launch: function() {
// Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
// Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.home'));
    },  
    onUpdated: function() {        
            Ext.Msg.confirm(
   "Application Update",   "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
                               function(buttonId) {             
                        if (buttonId === 'yes') {                   
                    window.location.reload();
                                            }                          
            }
                        );                      
                  }
});
```

**maincontroller.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controler.maincontroller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',   
    xtype: 'controllerpanel',
     refs : {
        homecontroller : 'firstdiv',        
    },
    views : [    'home', 'firstpage'  ],    
    config: {
        control: {
            '#firstdiv': {
                // On the tap event, call onNewTap
                tap: 'onFirstImageTap'
            }
        }
    },  
    launch: function() {
        // When our controller is launched, create an instance of our User view and add it to the viewport
        // which has a card layout
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.home'));                
    },  
    onFirstImageTap: function() {
        // When the user taps on the button, create a new reference of our New view, and set it as the active
        // item of Ext.Viewport
        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('MyApp.view.firstpage'));
            }
});
```

**main.js (view)**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {


        items: [  
        {
        xtype: 'homecontainer'
        },
        {
           xtype: 'settingcontainer'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'firstcontainer'
        }
        ]
    }
});
```

**home.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.home', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'homecontainer', 
    config: {   
    title: 'Home',  
    cls: 'maincss',      
    html: [
                '<div id=firstdiv>',
                '<img src="resources/images/1.jpg" height="25%" width="25%" />',            
                '</div>',   
               '<img src="resources/images/2.jpg" height="25%" width="50%" />',
               '<img src="resources/images/3.jpg" height="25%" width="25%" />',       
                '<img src="resources/images/4.jpg" height="25%" width="25%" />',               
                '<img src="resources/images/5.jpg" height="25%" width="25%" />',        
               '<img src="resources/images/6.jpg" height="25%" width="50%" />',     
               '<img src="resources/images/7.jpg" height="50%" width="25%"/>',  
               '<img src="resources/images/8.jpg" height="25%" width="25%" />',
               '<img src="resources/images/9.jpg" height="25%" width="25%"/>',
               '<img src="resources/images/10.jpg" height="25%" width="25%"/>',
               '<img src="resources/images/11.jpg" height="25%" width="25%"/>',
               '<img src="resources/images/12.jpg" height="25%" width="50%"/>',

               ].join("")
    }
});
```

**firstpage.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.firstpage', {
     extend: 'Ext.Container',   
      xtype: 'firstcontainer',
    cls: 'setting',
    config: {
        title: 'Setting',
        iconCls: 'settings',     
    html: [
    'first page',
               ].join("")
    }
});
```

setting.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.setting', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'settingcontainer',
    cls: 'setting',
    config: {
        title: 'Setting',
    html: [
             'setting page',
               ].join("")
    }
});
```

Comment: When you tap on an image, the view should change. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes exactly                                                                           When you tap on an image, the view should change.  Geeniewanted May 3 at 13:03

Answer (score 0):

This code might give you an idea.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.home', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'homecontainer',
    config: {
        title: 'Home',
        cls: 'maincss',
        html: [
            '<div id=firstdiv>',
                '<img src="resources/images/1.jpg" height="25%" width="25%"/>',
            '</div>',
            '<img src="resources/images/2.jpg" height="25%" width="50%" />',
            '<img src="resources/images/3.jpg" height="25%" width="25%" />',
            '<img src="resources/images/4.jpg" height="25%" width="25%" />',
            '<img src="resources/images/5.jpg" height="25%" width="25%" />',
            '<img src="resources/images/6.jpg" height="25%" width="50%" />',
            '<img src="resources/images/7.jpg" height="50%" width="25%"/>',
            '<img src="resources/images/8.jpg" height="25%" width="25%" />',
            '<img src="resources/images/9.jpg" height="25%" width="25%"/>',
            '<img src="resources/images/10.jpg" height="25%" width="25%"/>',
            '<img src="resources/images/11.jpg" height="25%" width="25%"/>',
            '<img src="resources/images/12.jpg" height="25%" width="50%"/>',
         ].join(""),
         listeners: {
            show: function (panel) {
                var el = panel.element,
                    image = el.down('#firstdiv');
                    image.on('tap', function (e, t) {
                        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(
                                Ext.create('MyApp.view.firstpage'));
                    }, panel);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

[Here is a link to the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Gmn8v/)

Comment: Thanks FOR your Answers.. this project is completed and thanks Again! for sharing your Knowledge

Answer (score 0):

That code works for a specific DOM.  Using the same code this is how I made 15 different images open a new view.

```
var el = panel.element,
events = el.down('#events');
events.on('tap', function (e, t) {
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('OrchardApp.view.Events'));},
panel.animateActiveItem(1, {type:'slide', direction:'left'}));
```

To add more images where I have events = change it to the name of the img you would like to be a trigger.  Add as many as you like.  The last three lines copy and paste changing the name of the view (in my case Events and name of this build is OrchardApp so change that to whatever yours happens to be.  Ignore the last line.  I can't get that to work right now but do add the

```
panel));
```

at the end

So, for example, you could have...

```
events = el.down('#events');
contact = el.down('#contact');
about = el.down('#about');
```

then the rest of the code with the views you wish to navigate.

Hope that helps.  Now if someone can just tell me how to make that animation work I'd be grateful.

Comment: Thanks FOR your Answers.. this project is completed and thanks Again! for sharing your Knowledge